# File missing from working copy Xcode 8

Tags: xcode8

I have somehow created a copy of my project folder inside my project folder A LOT times.

So to explain it, its like

First folder (pr.folder)
     Files.swift
     pr.folder
        Files.swift
        pr.folder
            etc

So from 60mb my project lifted to 900mb. So i deleted the first wrong created folder that had the rest of wrong created files and now again the project is 60mb.

The problem now is that i have 999+ warnings because I deleted these files and the warning is that the file is missing from working copy.

Is there anyway to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you done f'ed up bro

Comment: @OleksiyMartynov haha I know and I figured it out when i tried to compress it and saw that it was 900mb

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Missing from working copy` is usually in reference to your `git` working copy (git thinks there's a file missing) - adding a new commit with the file deleted should silence the warnings.

Comment: When i created the project i selected to have git local in my computer. How can I add a new commit and what will it happen it will create a new folder or what ? Thanks for your answer

Comment: Git is version control software. It helps you keep track of changes to your code over time. You can read up on it here: https://git-scm.com/, or lots of other places. But it's a lot to take in and if you weren't already using it and just want to silence the warnings, you can stop tracking your project from Xcode -> Source Control -> (name of your project) -> Configure

Comment: And when i click configure should i delete master from branches?

Comment: Actually I can't delete what should I do?

Comment: Staging files with `git add *` sealed the deal.